# Signing an apk. Is this a measure of securing against penetration attacks?

Tags: android, security, penetration-testing

**My questions:**

When I am signing my apk for release, does a checksum number created for securing my apk for penetration attacks?

So if someone gets his hands on my apk and is able to open it and change the code, will the signature change?

Will I know that it has been altered?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Yes .apk signature changes if apk is created from different Android Studio.

Comment: Hope this help you .-> http://security.stackexchange.com/a/67014

Comment: I would add that you want to use proguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If someone gets his hands on my apk and is able to open it and change the code, will the signature change?

Yes.

> so that I know that it has been altered?

Not usually, as usually part of the changes of the code will be to remove any tamper-detection code that you added. An inexperienced crook might tamper with your app and leave your tamper-detection code in there, but you should not assume that this will be the case.

Mostly, it is implemented because the tampered APK cannot be used to upgrade an existing installed APK, as the signatures do not match.

Also, if you have a suite of apps:

- If you are using `signature` permissions to secure communications between those apps, the tampered app will not be able to participate in those communications
- Apps in your suite could check the signature of other apps in your suite and detect the tampering (assuming that those apps themselves were not tampered with)

Comment: it will change even if the assets will be changed? I am making this questions because when writing,  for example in cordoba, the files are written in pure html and stored as assets

Comment: @libathos: "it will change even if the assets will be changed?" -- AFAIK, yes.